# How do I fix my label text not changing for a countdown timer in Kivy?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to add a timer to my program in python and kivy but the label doesnt change text from 60 to 59, 58.... till 0. It doesnt show any errors in the terminal so I have no idea what is wrong in the code.

Code from .py file:

```
from email import utils
from fileinput import filename
from pathlib import Path
from random import random
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
import json
import glob
import random
from datetime import datetime

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label, 1)
    
    def update_label(self, *args):
        self.root.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.root.ids.counter.text) - 1)

    def StartTest(self):
        self.manager.current = "main_Screen"

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Code from .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:import utils kivy.utils
<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0d')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    GridLayout:            
        Label:
            id: counter
            text: "60"

<RootWidget>:
    MainScreen:
        name: "main_screen"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `on_start` to `on_enter`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I changed the function name and am getting this error 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'root'

Comment: Yes, that error message is telling you what the problem is.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I dont know how to fix it tho, could you please help me?

Comment: In your `MainScreen` class, where you reference `self.root`, remove the `root` part.